# How to convert binary to downloadable file extension?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a binary response coming from the **backend** with **filename** and the **type** of it to be downloaded. Here is the code which I am receiving from the backend response:

```
01 00 00 00 78 02 00 00 6c 02 00 00 91 16 a2 3d ....x...l....... 9d e3 a6 4d 8a 4b b4 38 77 bc b1 b7 01 00 00 00 ...M.K.8w....... 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 dc 07 07 00 ................ 05 00 06 00 0c 00 30 00 2f 00 58 01 0f e5 52 9a ......0...X...R. 01 00 00 00 78 02 00 00 6c 02 00 00 91 16 a2 3d ....x...l....... 9d e3 a6 4d 8a 4b b4 38 77 bc b1 b7 01 00 00 00 ...M.K.8w....... 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 dc 07 07 00 ................ 05 00 06 00 0c 00 30 00 2f 00 58 01 0f e5 52 9a ......0...X...R.
```

**The output of the above is** : "@@" which I want to write in the type (xlsx,csv,txt) depending on the type receiving from the backend and download it on my local.

**In my service file:**

```
public downloadFile() {
const url = 'http://localhost:3300/star';

return this.http.get(url, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + "token",
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  }), responseType: 'blob'
}).pipe(
  tap(
    data => console.log('You received data'),
    error => console.log(error)
  )
);
```

}
**In the component file:**

```
this.service.downloadFile().subscribe((res) => {

  //res value is : Blob {size: 519, type: "text/html"}

  // Using file-saver to save the file
  saveAs(res, `demo.xlsx`);
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

I don't know what to do exactly from the client end and what is need to be done from the backend side as well to make it work. I read somewhere base64 is not advisable be sent from the server as the file size grows huge.

One thing is clear that I might huge file size data from the backend, for instance I might receive binary for xlsx file which could be 100 MB in size.

What to do to handle download from the client end? It can be bulk download

Please help in this regard. Thank you.

Comment: You have conflicting function names: `downloadFile` but calling `downloadExcelFile`? Change the `responseType` to `blob` and this should work fine. You don't want JSON as the response.

Comment: have you tried adding the `download` attribute? `<a href="/path/to/endpoint" download="demo.xlsx">Download</a>`

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thank you for your comment. The function name was just typo I have update the post. I changed it to just blob, the file is getting downloaded but it is showing "The file format is invalid." It is not opening up. Am I doing it in a right way?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn In my case, I am getting a response in binary form and I need to use it and download it in a particular  format

Comment: Try adding the third parameter `true` to `saveAs(res, 'demo.xlsx', true)`. It is unlikely to fix the issue, but will remove that potential.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I tried this as well. It's still showing the same error. The way I am doing it, is it the ideal of doing it? Please do let me know or if you any other option so that I can implement it

Comment: Often times, the "bad file" is actually retrieved that way from the source and this gets misinterpreted as the client being the issue. Use curl to grab the source and pipe it directly to a file. If you cannot open that file, the issue is with the source. I don't know what the `saveFile()` API is doing behind the scenes, but that could also (unlikely) cause. You may have to simply manually do it yourself.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Okay thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
/* TODO: replace the blob content with your byte[] */
const blob = new Blob([yourBinaryDataAsAnArrayOrAsAString], {type: "application/octet-stream"});
const fileName = "fileNAme.fileExtension";
```